# How to make dummies out of a continuum variable

Tags: pandas, dummy-variable

I'm quite new to programming and I couldnt find this anywhere. Basically, one of my variables has a range of 0 to 200000 and I'm trying to create a dummy for 0 and >0 values using pd.get_dummies, but I can't figure out how, can anyone help me with this one? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gabriel, to help get you the best possible answer, please see the page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, if this is homework, please see the page https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

Consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(OneVar=[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 9]))
```

Use `pd.get_dummies` on a boolean series

```
pd.get_dummies(df.OneVar.gt(0))

   False  True 
0      1      0
1      0      1
2      1      0
3      0      1
4      1      0
5      0      1
6      0      1
7      1      0
8      1      0
9      0      1
```

With renamed columns

```
pd.get_dummies(df.OneVar.gt(0)).rename(
    columns=dict(enumerate(['IsZero', 'GtZero'])))

   IsZero  GtZero
0       1       0
1       0       1
2       1       0
3       0       1
4       1       0
5       0       1
6       0       1
7       1       0
8       1       0
9       0       1
```